Create foreign keys to references to other tables and also have matching with mapping table
I'm using SQL Server and setup 4 tables with many references between them
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message] 
(
    [Id]             [BIGINT] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ConversationId] [BIGINT] NOT NULL 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Conversation] ([Id]),
    [UserId]         [BIGINT] NOT NULL 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Conversation] 
(
    [Id] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    -- other columns
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] 
(
    [Id] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    -- other columns
);

-- this table is a mapping table mapping Conversation and User table, using pair of composite keys
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Conversation_Users]   
(
    [ConversationId] BIGINT  NOT NULL,
    [UserId]         BIGINT  NOT NULL,
    -- other columns
    CONSTRAINT [PK__Conversation_Users] 
        PRIMARY KEY (ConversationId, UserId),  -- this defines composite keys
    CONSTRAINT [FK__Conversat_Users_User] 
        FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES [User](Id), -- this defines reference to User table
    CONSTRAINT [FK__Conversat_Users_Conv] 
        FOREIGN KEY (ConversationId) REFERENCES [Conversation](Id) -- this defines reference to Conversation table
)

Currently, Message table has 2 difference foreign keys to Conversation and User table. These references also ensure the Message.ConversationId and Message.UserId field must exist in 2 corresponding tables, this works fine.
But I also need these pair of foreign keys must exist in Conversation_Users, too. This doesn't work correctly in my database
How can I setup this mapping correctly?

Show us your DDL of your table(s) and then explain which foreign key definition(s) which aren't working as you want.

@ThomA I've edited the original post above

So whichis the FOREIGN KEY that isn't working as you expect? All those keys reference one column, not two, have you omitted the one that is to be used against Conversation_Users?

the one isn't working is the pair of references from Message to Conversation_Users. I tried to update these foreign keys in Message table to the values which doesn't exist in Conversation_Users. But every single foreign key works fine when being reference to coresponding table

Because it's just checking the user exists in Users not Conversation_Users.

that's the point. how can I implement to fix the problem.? create another foreign key to reference to Conversation_Users, too?

If you want a key to reference 2 columns, just design it with 2 columns, the syntax accepts a delimited list of columns:
ALTER TABLE dbo.Message ADD CONSTRAINT FK__Conversation_Users_ConvUser FOREIGN KEY (ConversationId, UserId) REFERENCES dbo.Conversation_Users (ConversationId, UserId);

Though you might be better off using a surrogate key on Conversation_Users and then using that:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Conversation_Users] ( -- this table is a mapping table mapping Conversation and User table, using pair of composite keys
    ConversationUserID int IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK__Conversation_Users PRIMARY KEY,
    [ConversationId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [UserId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    -- other columns
    CONSTRAINT [UQ__Conversation_Users] UNIQUE (ConversationId, UserId), -- this defines composite keys
    --CONSTRAINT [FK__Conversat_Users_User] FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES [User](Id), -- this defines reference to User table
    CONSTRAINT [FK__Conversat_Users_Conv] FOREIGN KEY (ConversationId) REFERENCES [Conversation] (Id) -- this defines reference to Conversation table
) GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Message] (
    [Id] [BIGINT] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ConversationUserID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK__Conversation_Users_ConvUser REFERENCES Conversation_Users (ConversationUserID)
);


the primary key ConversationUserID in Conversation_Users I tried and used it for a long time ago. Now, the design changed, and that primary key is removed and pair of composite keys is a replacement

did you mean to use only FK__Conversation_Users_ConvUser constraint and drop the 2 constraints exist before? (FK__Conversat_Users_User, FK__Conversat_Users_Conv)

If you have a FOREIGN KEY to dbo.Conversation_Users you don't need one to Conversation or Users, no, @MingHieu . The relationship is already implicit due to the relationship between Conversation_Users and Conversation/Users.

it works, man. Just add a relationship between Message and Conversation_Users and drop the existing references between Message and Conversation / Users. the new reference will also keep reference to Conversation / Users worked correctly
